# Combine two lists into a dictionary and merge value if key is the same

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I am writing a python code to combine two lists into a dictionary. One list may have duplicate values and the other one has unique values, here is an example:

```
A_list=["a","b","c","b"];
B_list=["xx","123","345","cdf"]
```

When they get combined, I want the dictionary like this:

```
Dict={"a":"xx","b":["123","cdf"],"c":"345"]
```

Comment: Downvoted because: [No code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode)

Comment: It's usually best to have consistent structure, so you should make the values all be lists rather than a mix of strings and lists.

Comment: Then it will be easy to create the result using `defaultdict(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each index of list A.

Grab the item in list A and list B at that index.

If the result dictionary already has the key from list A, then convert the value of that item to a list (if it isn't already) and append the item from list B.

Otherwise make a new entry in the dictionary with the key from list A and the value from list B.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently here's the simple python code to do this

```py
def dict_generator(l1,l2):
    res = dict()
    
    if(len(l1)!=len(set(l1))):
        for i,j in zip(l1,l2):
            if i in res.keys():
                res[i].append(j)
                
            else:
                res[i] = [j]
    else:
        for i,j in zip(l2,l1):
            if i in res.keys():
                res[i].append(j)
                
            else:
                res[i] = [j]
                
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way for you to understand:

```
a=["a","b","c","b","b"]
b=["xx","123","345","cdf","xyz"]
d={}
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i] in list(d.keys()):
        # converting the single value to a list   
        if type(d[a[i]]) is not list:
            c=d[a[i]]
            d[a[i]]=[c]
        d[a[i]].append(b[i])
    else:
       d[a[i]]=b[i]
print(d)
```

Output-

```
{'a': 'xx', 'b': ['123', 'cdf', 'xyz'], 'c': '345'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally not a good idea to have the data type of a value depend on its number of items.  You should consider using lists for all values instead of sometimes lists and sometimes strings.  That will save you a lot of conditional code down the line:

```
A = ["a","b","c","b"];
B = ["xx","123","345","cdf"]

D = dict()
D.update((a,D.get(a,[])+[b]) for a,b in zip(A,B)))

print(D)
{'a': ['xx'], 'b': ['123', 'cdf'], 'c': ['345']}
```

If you must have irregular data types, you can retrofit the type change on the resulting uniform data:

```
D = {a:b if len(b)>1 else b[0] for a,b in D.items()}

print(D)
{'a': 'xx', 'b': ['123', 'cdf'], 'c': '345'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use zip and if key in dict check whether the value is a list then append if it's the same key:

```
A_list = ["a","b","c","b",'b']
B_list = ["xx","123","345","cdf","www"]

res = {}

for a,b in zip(A_list, B_list):
    res[a] = (k:=res[a],[k])[type(k)!=list]+[b] if a in res else b

print(res)

# {'a': 'xx', 'b': ['123', 'cdf', 'www'], 'c': '345'}
```